# c# programatically created list event-handler howto

Tags: checkbox, event-handling, windows-phone

Can anyone tell me how to connect a click event of a checkbox inside of a programatically created list? So far I have only seen examples of connecting events of objects created statically and not dynamically allocated from code.

the list is created as described in the snippet below:

```
namespace CustomListApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
            {
                CustomListBoxItem clbi = new CustomListBoxItem();
                clbi.Title.Text = "This is item " + i;
                clbi.Condition.IsChecked = i % 2 == 0;
                CustomListBox.Items.Add(clbi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the CustomListBoxItem has this structure:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomListApp.CustomListBoxItem"[...]>

    <Grid x:Name="ListBoxItemGrid" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" Height="65">
        <CheckBox x:Name="Condition" Height="67" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" Click="Condition_Click" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Height="65" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,0,0,0" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="294" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you can create a typ of your elements which you want to add to your listbox. And then you can check for a click like this:

```
<YOUR DATA TYPE> data = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as <YOUR DATA TYPE>;
```

Then you can work with this data. I hope that I could help you with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like

```
cbi.Condition.Click += new_click_handler;
```

where new_click_handler is the new click handler you want to add?

but do you *need* to add a new handler to each item programatically?  can't you just reference the item inside that already existing `Condition_Click` handler you already have in your xaml?